Rational to use McDonald's Omega as a reliability measure for an unweighted sum score
In recent literature reporting McDonald's omega as a reliability estimate is clearly favoured over reporting coefficient alpha (e.g. McNeish, 2017). One argument often given is that coefficient alpha (or Cronbach's alpha) assumes a (essentially) tau-euqivalent measurement model, i.e. the factor loadings have to be equal, whereas McDonald's omega allows for differing loadings. Since there are multiple takes on omega, let's just focus on the total omega in a unidimensional scale for simplicity's sake, as specified by McNeish (2017):

(where $\lambda_i$ is the factor loading and $\theta_{ii}$ is the error/residual variance of the i-th item)
In the article McNeish writes:

Omega (McDonald, 1970, 1999) is a commonly recommended measure of composite reliability that is available in multiple software programs. Omega is designed for congeneric scales, where the items vary in how strongly they are related to the construct being measured (i.e., in a factor analysis setting, the loadings would not be assumed to be equal). In other words, where tau equivalence is not assumed. Composite reliability is appropriate when the items from a scale are unit-weighted to form the total scale score but the scale itself in congeneric (Bentler, 2007; Geldhof et al., 2014). A unit-weighted scale means that the total score of the scale is calculated by adding up the raw scores (or reverse coded raw scores, if appropriate) of the individual items: Each item is weighted equally.

This feels counterintuitive to me: Let's say, for example, a CFA showed that a congeneric model (freed loadings) fit the sample data better than the more restrictive tau-equivalent model, so we decide to use omega instead of coefficient alpha. However, subsequent analyses would be done with a sum/mean score that is literally computed based on equally weighting the items, even though we had just shown in the CFA that this type of measurement model would not fit our data well.
My Question:
Could someone maybe provide some rational, why it makes sense to report McDonald's omega for a score that is made up of equally weighted items?

Source:
McNeish, D. (2017). Thanks coefficient alpha, we’ll take it from here. Psychological Methods, 23(3), 412–433. https://doi.org/10.1037/met0000144

Both alpha and omega are internal homogeneity, reliability measures for equal-weight summative constructs. Omega does not assume tau-equivalence in terms of loadings (loadings are coefficients in the linear combination of calculation the item by the factor(s)), but it does assume that the weights in linear combination of calculation the factor (construct) by the items are used equal. It looks to me so.

That is an interesting point. Could you maybe add a citation where I can read more about it? And do I understand your comment correctly that describing the items as being predicted by the factor through differing weights is "allowed" for omega, but the factor (i.e.  manifest score of the factor) is still assumed to be estimated/computed by equally weighting all items?

Alpha and omega are for the construct score computed as the simple (unweighted) sum of values. But one may adopt a weighted sum to estimate the construct score. For example, use some of the number of methods to compute "the factor score". The unweighted, simple sum approach is a particular case of the "coarse" (Cattell's) method. Omega is a internal homogeneity coefficient with the position "I will be computing the construct as the simple sum, while I want to recognize that the factor loadings are unequal".

A (unit-weighted) sum score is different than computing a factor or latent variable score using the actual factor loadings, $\lambda_{i}$. Internal consistency reliability is about sum scores, so any metric for this kind of reliability will apply to the sum scores, not factor scores (which would depend on the weights and also on whatever scale the latent variable is set to). Indeed, the only way to compute internal consistency with $\alpha$ is with the sum or total score over $k$ items or tests or testlets:
$$
\alpha = {k \over k-1 } \left(1 - {\sum_{i=1}^k \sigma^2_{y_i} \over \sigma^2_Y} \right)
$$
that is, $\sigma^{2}_{Y}$ is the variance of the total score and $\sigma^{2}_{y_i}$ are the individual item variances. Alpha and omega are related in the following way (see McDonald, 1999 p. 93):
$$
\omega - \alpha = \left(\frac{m}{m-1} \right)\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}_{Y}} \right)(\text{Var}(\lambda_{j}))
$$
With $\tau$ equivalence, this term $\text{Var}(\lambda_{j})$ is zero (all loadings equal) and the difference is zero. When the loadings are unequal $\alpha$ is an underestimate $\omega$ is less biased, but is dependent on estimation of the $\lambda_{j}$’s.
The critical part, is that the factor loadings are used to estimate observed and true score variances, not as a linear model of the total score $Y$ per se. This is necessary with the congeneric model, as there is no good way to estimate these variances from un-transformed information in the sample covariance matrix (i.e., we can't do the simple summing of variances as in the above formula for $\alpha$).
McDonald motivates this by decomposing a total test score in the following way:
$$
Y = \sum_j X_j = \left(\sum_j \lambda_j \right)F + \sum_j E_j + \sum_j \mu_j
$$
The "true-score" part of $Y$ is $\left(\sum_j \lambda_j \right)F$, setting the mean to zero we drop the last term involving $\mu$ and we have $Y = T_Y + E_y$. By the assumption of independence of $T_Y$ and $E_y$, the variance of the sum is the sum of the variances:
$$
\sigma^2_Y = \left(\sum_j \lambda_j\right)^2 + \sum_j \psi_j^2
$$
Reliability, in general can be defined as the ratio of true-score variance to total variance in Y, and we recover the equation for omega:
$$
\omega = \frac{\left(\sum_j \lambda_j\right)^2}{ \left(\sum_j \lambda_j\right)^2+ \sum_j \psi_j^2}
$$
But again, our goal, and what we are communicating with these estimates of reliability is what proportion of true score variance (to total variance) does a total or sum (or mean score) give us. The factor loadings simply are the way to estimate true-score variance.

Thank you for this answer. I believe this sentence "Internal consistency reliability is about sum scores, so any metric for this kind of reliability will apply to the sum scores" should answer my question but I am still confused about this concept. Could you maybe elaborate on why this is the case?

I may have over done it, but have a look now. I cannot recommend the McDonald book enough. He lays things out so nicely with very accessible explanations. Raykov and Marcoulides (2011) adapt some of the content and show how you can use Mplus to generate it, but I think McDonald's approach is clearer.
